# Getting / receiving data from an online text file

Tags: c#, file-upload, upload

I've been working on this for a few days and can't seem to get it working.

I want to be able to get, and send text (numbers to be specific) to a online file where it can be stored.

At the moment I use:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string text = wc.DownloadString("domain.com");            
MessageBox.Show(text);
```

But it's not great as I can't easily send data, I also want to be able to delete data when its been received a certain amount of times.

I want each item to get uploaded to the same same file, so they can be received individually, and removed one they have been received a certain amount of time.

I have full have access to a web server if needed.

How do I achieve this?

Have tried:

```
            WebClient WC = new WebClient();
            string myContent = "test";
            string responseString = WC.UploadString("ftp://192.99.1??9.66/www/test.txt", myContent);
```

Obviously didnt have the question marks.

Comment: If what you expose is all you need, the easiest way to go would be FTP.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain more? I am quite new to c#

Comment: Well, Patrick already gave you details. `WebClient` does what you want. If for some reason you need a more advanced solution (security, performant batch uploads/downloads...), search for a FTP library that suits all your needs, there are plenty of it out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post it as a regular HTTP request, or use something like FTP to write files.

You have the built-in upload methods that do the appropriate HTTP post or FTP requests in the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx) class already:

```
byte[] responseArray = wc.UploadFile("ftp://domain/thefile.txt" , @"C:\anyfile.txt");

byte[] responseArray = wc.UploadFile("http://domain/thefile.txt" , @"C:\anyfile.txt");
```

The last one needs some sort of technology that handles the HTTP POST request, like a webservice. The first one needs an active and accepting FTP server.

Or to send a `string`:

```
string myContent = "some data here";

string responseString = wc.UploadString("ftp://domain/thefile.txt" , myContent);
```

Comment: sorry Patrick. It just didn't send the text "test" to the .txt file.

Comment: managed to get it working using http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/data-to-ftp-upload-by-stream-copy

Comment: with this method http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/data-to-ftp-upload-by-stream-copy , how would I get it to make a new line of text each time rather then just deleting the last one? and yes, I will accept it as youve helped me heaps.

Comment: Read the file from the server, alter it, write it back.

Comment: okay, I see. Got it all working, setting wise. Any idea how to make it only receive the first line of text?